# Escape sequence for the escape key

Tags: ssh, terminal, escaping

On an SSH terminal, there is a command that takes over the terminal window, and it says I can press escape to end it.

My SSH terminal does not handle the escape key. What is the escape sequence (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+something) that I can use in its place. (or is there one)

I can just disconnect from SSH and connect again but I thought I would go ahead check if there was an escape sequence for the escape key. Would that even work?

Comment: What SSH/terminal program is that? Seems very strange the it wouldn't handle the escape key.

Comment: Turns out that although Iain's answer is correct, it was not the cause of the problem. It was actually the SSH server on the out of band management. It works on Serial, but not SSH. And the SSH client does indeed handle the escape key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> ( ^[ ).

filler

Comment: Aka the [ASCII escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character).